# How often is $\sin(a^n) $ positive or negative?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

Let $a > 1$. Define

$$
f(x,a) = \#\{n:\sin(a^n) \ge 0, n \in N, 1 \le n \le x\},
$$

$$
g(x,a) = \#\{n:\sin(a^n) < 0, n \in N, 1 \le n \le x\}.
$$

**Questions**

1. What is known about the growth rate of $f(x,a)$ and $g(x,a)$?
2. Can the quantity $\Delta(x,a) = f(x,a) - g(x,a)$ it be bounded in terms of $x$ and $a$?

**My thoughts**:

Since $\sin(\theta)$ is a circular function, I would look at the distribution of the remainder when $a^n$ is divided by $2\pi$. If the remainder is uniformly distributed in $(0,2\pi)$ then $\sin(a^n)$ is equally likely to be positive or negative hence I would expect $f(x,a) \sim g(x,a) \sim x/2$.

Comment: Are n and x integer? Or only n?

Comment: Yes, $n$ is a natural number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerations for large $x$. $\enspace k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ depends on $n$.

$\sin a^n\geq 0$ : $\enspace\displaystyle 0\leq \frac{a^n}{\pi} -2k\leq 1$

$\sin a^n< 0$ : $\enspace\displaystyle -1< \frac{a^n}{\pi} -2k< 0$

The full circle is $\enspace\displaystyle -1< \frac{a^n}{\pi} -2k\leq 1$ .

Therefore $f(x,a)\approx g(x,a)$ because $|(-1;0)|=|[0;1]|=1$.

Number of cases $-1\le\sin a^n \le 1$ : $\enspace\displaystyle f(x,a)+g(x,a)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ for $\enspace\displaystyle -1< \frac{a^n}{\pi} -2k\leq 1$

Therefore $\displaystyle f(x,a)\approx \frac{x}{2}$ and $\displaystyle g(x,a)\approx \frac{x}{2}$ .